# Does Ionic View Application trigger 'deviceready'

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic-view

Ionic has a 'deviceready' listener that can detect if the device is ready and if so can trigger more function to do work.

I have a test application that works when I plug my iphone to computer, but it fail to launch the function associated with 'deviceready' when I am launching from ionic view. I am wondering if Ionic View application actually will trigger 'deviceready' or not since the app is technically inside ionic view container.

Comment: anybody has experience want to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case if anybody is interested. this already have an answer. http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/does-ionic-view-app-detect-deviceready/32026
Use $ionicPlatform.ready instead of document.addEventListener('deviceready')

Comment: also, ionic view app would not get device token.